# ActionScript 3 - Opening External files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, powerpoint

Does anyone know of a way to open an external file from Flash in ActionScript 3 without the request first going through the browser.  Specifically, I want to open a PowerPoint presentation directly with PowerPoint.

I've tried:

```
var url:String = "MyContent/My presentation.pptx";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
navigateToURL(request);
```

Which works well, but it first makes the request to the browser instead of opening it natively with PowerPoint.

NOTE: This is a desktop Flash piece that won't be on the web.

Comment: if its desktop , i think you should be using Adobe AIR which can access the local file system.

anyway urlrequest's can use relative urls

I use,

new URLRequest('assets/xml/sprites.xml');

and it works fine for me .... what is the error you get?

Comment: oops the above comment i lost its formatting ... hope its still readable :S

Comment: It works find, but it opens with the browser and not the default which would be PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need one of the external wrappers. Either Zinc as James told you, Adobe AIR or also Open Source alternatives such as HippoHX.

Should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

i'm fairly certain that this isn't possible with just flash or air for that matter.  Mainly because of sandboxing issues. Being able to open up other apps could cause security loop holes.

It should be possible through [Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/) but it's a bit more work and obviously extra cost... still if you need it to happen it may be worth the cost.